# TkInter: understanding unbind function

Tags: python, tkinter, unbind

Does TkInter [unbind](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.unbind-method) function prevents the widget on which it is applied from binding further events to the widget ?

**Clarification:**

Let's say I bound events to a canvas earlier in a prgram:

```
 canvas.bind("<Button-1>",some_function)
```

Then at a certain point of the program, we no longer need those events:

```
 canvas.unbind("<Button-1>")
```

Can we later do something like this:

```
 canvas.bind("<Button-1>",OTHER_function)
```

Comment: My bad, I misread the question. Of course, this can be done. After unbinding a function from an event, you can then bind a function to the event.

Comment: It would be better to provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried and a clear description of the issue.

Comment: @jonrsharpe this question does not need an example given its nature. I am asking about the effect of a method that is not mine but offered by a library, so any one who had experience with it could answer. No need for code.

Comment: The question in its current form is pointless - the obvious answer is *"why don't you try it and see?"* But then you commented *"I have a real problem in binding an other event after unbinding"* - presumably you *have* tried it, but failed to make it work, so I would suggest skipping the interim steps and asking the question you actually want answering!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, unbinding an event doesn't prevent further bindings on the widget. You can bind an event, unbind it, and then bind it again at a later date as often as you want.