# tkinter ttk treeview colored rows

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I am trying to set colors to rows in a tkinter treeview object, using tags and tag_configure.

There has been an earlier discussion on coloring rows which is rather old and seems to work no longer for Python3:

[ttk treeview: alternate row colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878730/ttk-treeview-alternate-row-colors)

I have added a brief example. For me, all rows stay white, independent of whether I execute tag_configure prior or after the insert command.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
w = tk.Label(root, text="Hello, world!")
w.pack()

lb= ttk.Treeview(root, columns=['number', 'text'], show="headings", height =20)
lb.tag_configure('gr', background='green')
lb.column("number", anchor="center", width=10)    
lb.insert('',tk.END, values = ["1","testtext1"], tags=('gr',))
lb.insert('',tk.END, values = ["2","testtext2"])

lb.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

What has changed or what am I missing?

**EDIT:**
Seems that this is a new known bug with a workaround, but I don't get this working:
https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/tktview?name=509cafafae

**EDIT2:**
I am now using tk Version 8.6.10 (Build hfa6e2cd_0, Channel conda-forge) and python 3.7.3. Can anyone reproduce this error with this version of python and tk?

Comment: I've executed your code - it works. What is your Tkinter version? (To check it type `from tkinter import TkVersion; TkVersion` in interactive mode, though never use ; in your real code)

Comment: Tkinter version is 8.6, python version is 3.7.3

Comment: `no longer for Python3` -- this is an absolutely wrong sentence because Tk version is independent of Python version (though there is the default-installed Tk version, of course)

Comment: @Bryan Oakley Which version of python do you use? It does not work in my python 3.7.3. version, and I have some other similar code which works in my 2.7, so I was assuming that this is related to the python version. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: By the way, have you tried to set the style of the Treeview? I mean, `lb = ttk.Treeview(root, ...., style="Treeview")

Comment: @DemianWolf I have tried to implement the code of that workaround, but did not get this style command working properly. It does not work if I just add style=Treeview" to the ttk.Treeview command.

Answer (score 4):

You no longer need to use fixed_map the bug was fixed in tkinter version 8.6.
The following code works fine for me using tkinter 8.6 and python 3.8.2 running in Linux.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

def fixed_map(option):
    return [elm for elm in style.map("Treeview", query_opt=option) if elm[:2] != ("!disabled", "!selected")]

root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style()
style.map("Treeview", foreground=fixed_map("foreground"), background=fixed_map("background"))

w = tk.Label(root, text="Hello, world!")
w.pack()

lb= ttk.Treeview(root, columns=['number', 'text'], show="headings", height =20)
lb.tag_configure('odd', background='green')
lb.tag_configure('even', background='lightgreen')

lb.column("number", anchor="center", width=10)
lb.insert('', tk.END, values = ["1","testtext1"], tags=('odd',))
lb.insert('', tk.END, values = ["2","testtext2"], tags=('even',))
lb.insert('', tk.END, values = ["3","testtext3"], tags=('odd',))
lb.insert('', tk.END, values = ["4","testtext4"], tags=('even',))

lb.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: In windows, tkinter 8.6.8. and python 3.8.2 do not work. Which subversion of tkinter 3.8. are you using (you'll see it with `conda list tk`)

Comment: I'm not using Anaconda. The code above works in Linux, I tried it on Windows 10 and you will need to still use the fixed_map function to make it work. I edited the code to show this.

Comment: You can also have a look at this post maybe it will help, look at the working example at the end of the post, it's been tested in Windows and Linux. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61350804/tkinter-treeview-how-to-correctly-select-multiple-items-with-the-mouse

Comment: I have decided to only auto-award this answer since it is only a copy of my answer, so I am not sure that it deserves the full bounty. Unfortunately Chuck666 did not show up to collect his bounty. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

That answer of Chuck666 did the trick:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60949800/4352930

This code works

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

def fixed_map(option):
    # Returns the style map for 'option' with any styles starting with
    # ("!disabled", "!selected", ...) filtered out

    # style.map() returns an empty list for missing options, so this should
    # be future-safe
    return [elm for elm in style.map("Treeview", query_opt=option)
            if elm[:2] != ("!disabled", "!selected")]



root = tk.Tk()

style = ttk.Style()
style.map("Treeview", 
          foreground=fixed_map("foreground"),
          background=fixed_map("background"))

w = tk.Label(root, text="Hello, world!")
w.pack()

lb= ttk.Treeview(root, columns=['number', 'text'], show="headings", height =20)
lb.tag_configure('gr', background='green')
lb.column("number", anchor="center", width=10)    
lb.insert('',tk.END, values = ["1","testtext1"], tags=('gr',))
lb.insert('',tk.END, values = ["2","testtext2"])

lb.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I hope that Chuck666 copies his answer here since I think he has earned the bonus if he shows up.

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine:

```
lb= ttk.Treeview(root, columns=['number', 'text'], show="headings", height =20)
style = ttk.Style()
lb.tag_configure('gr', background='green')
lb.column("number", anchor="center", width=10)  
style.map('Treeview', background=[('selected', 'blue')])
lb.insert('',tk.END, values = ["1","testtext1"], tags=('gr',))
lb.insert('',tk.END, values = ["2","testtext2"])
```